# User defined positioning on a grid of html form fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, vue.js

I have a form with some input elements that I want to arrange on a grid according to users' preferences. Looking around I have come across [CSS grids](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

I am thinking about creating a CSS grid with *r* rows and *c* columns, and then using javascript to assign input elements to the grid's cells according to a user defined layout (for example, an object having the id of the input elements as keys and the (column-span) pairs as values).

I don't know if this is the best (or even a viable) solution, and it sounds like a lot of boilerplate code to change the CSS properties of the input elements. So my questions are: is this the right approach to this problem? Are there other (better, easier) approaches, not necessarily based on CSS grids?

I am using plain javascript and Vue.js, if it matters
(sorry for my imprecise wording, I am a hobbyist, self-taught developer).

Comment: Your question is really confusing to me. It is unclear what you try to achive, where you stuck or what your actual question is. What do you mean with fields? the grid-cards?

Comment: Sorry for my imprecise wording: with "fields" I refer to the input elements in the form. I want to layout these inputs in a grid-like way, according to user-defined preferences. So, for example, the input element with id="name" should be displayed in the first row and second column, while the input with id="address" should be displayed in the third row and first column, and so forth. My question is whether the approach based on CSS grids is viable or whether there are other (more effective, easier) approaches.

Comment: what is wrong with simply setting `grid-row`- and `grid-column`-properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) to assign elements to a position in the grid irrespective of their order in the DOM.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: "w x" "y z";
}

#a { grid-area: z; }
#b { grid-area: w; }
#c { grid-area: y; }
#d { grid-area: x; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="A">
  <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="B">
  <input id="c" type="text" placeholder="C">
  <input id="d" type="text" placeholder="D">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set an attribute to the input or any html tag.

If the ordering based on user-preferences, then I assume you will have a json object that tells the position of the fields in the form, so you can set an attribute to the html tag

```
<span data-column="0" data-row="0" />
<input type='text' data-column="1" data-row="0" />
or 
<input type='text' data-order="1:0" />
<input type='text' data-order="0:0" />
```

then when generating the form with a loop statement, you can then getAttribute/setAttribute with `document.getElementById().setAttribute('attrName','attrValue')`